# Accessing Object of Magento Admin Grid via Java-Script

Tags: javascript, magento, grid, adminhtml

I would like to access the JavaScript Object of the Magento Adminhtml Grid.
I want to reload the Grid after my Dialog is closed an the Ajax-Request to the Controller has finished.

If i modify the grid.js this is easy to make. But i don't want to modify the grid.js of magento itself.

Any ideas how i can access that object?

Answer (score 4):

Late answer, but maybe it will help someone

If you setup the grid in Grid.php like this:

```
parent::__construct();
$this->setId('your_grid_id');
.
.
.
```

from javascript, grid object is

```
your_grid_idJsObject
```

in your case

```
your_grid_idJsObject.reload();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can update your layout by this

```
<action method="addJs"><script>somepath/somefile.js</script></action>
```

For example, I needed to add javascript to sales->order grid.

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_index>
   <reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs"><script>somepath/somefile.js</script></action>
   </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_index>
```

js/somepath/somefile.js - this is path for file.
Hope this help.

Comment: This answer is off-topic and not related to question.