# Magento how to close loading-mask after gridJsObject is reloaded?

Tags: ajax, magento, grid

I followed the answer of Ionut in this question: [Accessing Object of Magento Admin Grid via Java-Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648881/accessing-object-of-magento-admin-grid-via-java-script)

But I found out there's a problem related to loading-mask. The loading-mask disappear when Ajax.request complete. But your_grid_idJsObject.reload(); does not belong to the Ajax request, so there is a delay (about 1-3 second) between when loading-mask disappear and when the grid is actually reloaded.

Do you know how to fix this?

Thank you very much. Any help would be appreciated.